# switch con casos de muchas posibilidades

Tags: c++

Tengo una duda.

```
switch(car1){
   case 'a':cout<<"es la letra A o B\n";
   case 'b':cout<<"es la letra A o B\n";
}
```

En este caso ¿es posible que cuando se ponen los casos poner que cuando quiera que car1 valga **a** o **b** diga el mensaje en vez de tener que escribir cada caso?

Answer (score 5):

Cuando un caso de `switch` no incluye `break`, se ejecutan todos los casos posteriores hasta encontrar un `break`, así que en tu caso:

```
switch(car1){
   case 'a':cout<<"es la letra A o B\n";
   case 'b':cout<<"es la letra A o B\n";
}
```

Cuando `car1` sea `'a'` se escribirá el mensaje `"es la letra A o B\n"` dos veces (el del caso `'a'` y después seguirá y escribirá el del del caso `'b'`. Cuando `car1` sea `'b'` el mensaje se escribirá una vez.

Por lo tanto:

```
switch(car1){
    case 'a':
    case 'A':
    case 'b':
    case 'B':
        cout<<"es la letra A o B\n";
}
```

Imprimirá el mismo mensaje, una vez, cuando `car1` sea `a`, `b`, `A` o `B`. Algunos compiladores emiten una alarma con el código anterior, para evitarla añade el atributo [`[[fallthrough]]` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/fallthrough)

```
switch(car1){
    case 'a':
        [[fallthrough]];
    case 'A':
        [[fallthrough]];
    case 'b':
        [[fallthrough]];
    case 'B':
        cout<<"es la letra A o B\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es que en cualquiera de los dos casos (A o B) imprima el mensaje solo deberias colocar

```
case 'a':  
case 'b':cout<<"es la letra A o B\n";  
         break;
```

Porque si es 'a' va a continuar hasta que encuentre algun `break;` que rompa el `switch`, si lo colocas en amnbos lados (como lo tienes tu) va a impimir 2 veces el mensaje si la letra es 'a'o 1 sola vez si es 'b'